# Copy string to clipboard and display into output window simultaeneously

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, gedit, clipboard

I am working in Ubuntu 14.04 and using Gedit.

Now I have below code(running from "External Tools" menu in Gedit) to get Gedit currently opened document's path to clipboard.

```
echo -n $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI | xclip -sel clip;
```

Now I also want to display the result of `echo -n $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI` into output window(with same "echo" statement), along with copying to clipboard.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

To copy the output to the clipboard also outputting to the current terminal you could simply use `tee`, which will output its `stdin` to any file passed to it as an argument and to `stdout`; you can use a process substitution running `xclip` to "fake" a regular file and output to it instead of to a regular file:

```
echo -n $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard)
```

Another option is to output to one of the free "default" pseudo-terminals (tty1 to tty6), which have a correspodent device file in "/dev" ("/dev/tty1" to "/dev/tty6"):

```
echo -n $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard) >/dev/tty1
```

Yet another option is to output to another "listening" pseudo-terminal using a named pipe; this requires a setup to set the "listening" terminal:

First open the "listening" terminal and run this script (for the sake of the example I'll assume that the script is running in `~/tmp`):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo fifo # creates a named pipe named "fifo" in the current working directory
trap 'rm fifo; exit 0' 1 2 3 13 15 # traps SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGPIPE and SIGTERM; removes "fifo" and exits upon the reception of each of them
while [ 1 ]; do
    cat fifo # outputs the content of "fifo"
done
```

This will create a named pipe named "fifo" in the current working directory and will continuously output its content until the script execution is halted;

Then using Gedit's External Tools run this modified version of the second command, which instead of redirecting the output to "/dev/tty1" redirects it to the named pipe:

```
echo -n $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard) >>~/tmp/fifo
```

Sample output using two `gnome-terminal` instances:

> Running the script on the right terminal

[image: screenshot1]

> Running `echo -n $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard) >>~/tmp/fifo` on the left terminal

[image: screenshot2]

> Hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[image: screenshot3]

[More informations on named pipes](http://thorstenball.com/blog/2013/08/11/named-pipes/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I can't test this now as I am at Home, Ubuntu is installed in my Office system, but I wanna know, is there something like "/dev/stdout" to print output to screen(not necessarily terminal but any std output) ?

Comment: @VickyDev You're welcome, yes, there's /dev/tty which always corresponds to the current terminal, so you could even do echo -n $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI | tee >/dev/tty | xclip -selection clipboard however that introduces an unuseful redirection, since the output is always printed to stdout, which by default is always the current terminal

Comment: @VickyDev Also maybe you meant other terminals. In that case you could use /dev/tty1 to /dev/tty6 to output to one of the other pseudo-terminals (not /dev/tty7); I'm too away from my machine, but there also ways to output to other pseudo-terminals like gnome-terminal using named pipes; they require a setup though, so I'll have to get back to my machine before posting an example

Comment: `@kos` Sure, please post a list along with reference link for named pipes, perhaps that's what I need, as I want to know options of output in Linux system. You can post it tomorrow.

Comment: @VickyDev Done, I've added an example per each of the those cases, plus a reference to an article on named pipes, which beside explaining them pretty well also shows many examples of usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really worked it up, I will check this and reply as soon as possible, kind of very busy right now.

Comment: `@kos` Any idea how can I pipe output to "printf" without any red error messages or exceptions ?

Comment: @VickyDev What messages are you getting exactly? Can you post an example?

Comment: `@kos` Maybe a warning, I am getting following message when I try to pipe output string to printf  `printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]`

Comment: `@kos` Piping output string to any separate variable and printing it along with copy to clipboard is also fine for me.

Comment: @VickyDev In your case the syntax should be printf '%s' $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI, is this what you're running?

Comment: `@kos` I appended '%s' like you said still the same warning.

Comment: @VickyDev Does the variable contains spaces? In that case you should quote it using double quotes; if not please post the full command, the problem should be somewhere else

Comment: `@kos` Here is the full script I am using `#!/bin/bash
origPath=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI
finalPath=`php -f /var/www/html/pathswapcmd.php basePath=$origPath`;
echo -n $finalPath | xclip -sel clip | printf;
printf '%s' $finalPath;
exit;
`

Comment: @VickyDev The error is in the line above. The error is because you don't specify a format in `printf`, but that wouldn't work regardless: you need to use `tee` like I write in the answer to print the output the terminal; `xclip` doesn't pipe `stdout` and `printf` doesn't read `stdin`. Use the command I put in the answer: `echo -n $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar self-answered question that was closed as a duplicate of this question. However it is quite different from the accepted answer here so I thought it warranted posting here.

---

## Use `xclip`

`xclip` allows you to save output to the clipboard. To install it use:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install xclip
```

Then use it like so:

```
$ ls -l | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard)

total 9788
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 9950180 Dec 12 09:13 QueryResults.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick    6491 Oct 31 12:18 StackQuery
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rick rick   55970 Dec 12 18:47 stack-to-blog.py
```

The output after the `ls` command appearing on your screen will also be in the clipboard ready to insert into most applications with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or `Right-Click` menu and then the `Paste` option.

## Create alias for `xclip` command

If you plan on using this more than once, you'll want to create an `alias`. Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and enter this line:

```
alias clip="tee >(xclip -selection clipboard)"
```

Then instead of typing:

```
ls -l | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard)
```

All you need to type is:

```
ls -l | clip
```

**NOTE:** After saving your `~/.bashrc` file, it is not ready to use until your next restart of the terminal or until you resource it with the command `. ~/.bashrc`